# PHP --> SQL Server + Excel file upload from a specific row

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a requirement in which, i need to upload an excel file into SQL Server database. It is working well till this point.

But sometimes i am getting excel file in such a way, that the first 2 rows and columns are empty rows. That is not even fixed every time. so the format of the table after upload is not as expected. It is assigning F1, F2 as column names for the table in SQL Server.

It varies from file to file. I want to program it in such away so that the user can enter the row number and the column number from where the actual data is starting. So that while upload it should from line 3 and column 2.

I don't know how to specify that row and column while uploading. 
Please help me to solve the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

You can use this to check if and where the data you expect is located in the excel.
If not you could try to find the first column/row with data and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can ask your user before starting upload (in form with input type="file") and after user uploads file and you show him an parsed excel data (by your script)..
To more concrete answer you should at least say, by what do you parse excel files and what excel format do you use...